# Terraform onwards for Already existing 100s of Resources in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-deployment

My org is using Multiple subscriptions and already have 100s of resources already existing in each of these subscriptions. Currently we create these resources from portal itself.
Is it still advisable to introduce Terraform now?

Import of resources Terraform suggest but is this advisable for 100s of existing resources?  Any relevant documentation how to start?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very helpful tool to accomplish your goal. https://github.com/Azure/aztfy

It can be used to import existing subscription from Azure and the terraform configuration files would be created automatically.

Installation instructions:

```
go install github.com/Azure/aztfy@latest
```

Usage:

```
aztfy resource-group-name
```

More detailed instructions can be found on the github page.